# Is the real solution of $\ln(x)=-e^x$ transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, roots, transcendental-numbers

The function $$f(x)=\ln(x)+ e^x$$ defined on $\mathbb R_+$ has a unique real root $u$. It satisfies $$\ln(u)=-e^u$$ and $$\frac{1}{u}=e^{e^u}$$ The numerical value is $$0.269874137573449223877\cdots $$

> Can $u$ be proven to be transcendental ?

- Numerical analysis with PARI/GP with the algdep-command reveals large coefficients upto degree $50$ indicating that $u$ is probably transcendental.
- The Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem does not help , $e^{e^u}$ need not be transdencental for algebraic $u$. Perhaps, someone can prove that $u$ is transcendental assuming Schanuel's conjecture.
- If a transcendentality proof is not possible undonditionally, can at least the irrationality be proven unconditionally ?

Comment: Schanuel's conjecture indeed gives the result, as we need $\mathbb Q(u,e^u,e^u,e^{e^u})/\mathbb Q$ to have transcendence degree $2$ - if $u$ were algebraic, so would $e^{e^u}=1/u$ and $e^u$ would be the only transcendental element.

Comment: @Wojowu If you formulate this as an answer , I will upvote and accept. Thank you for the information.

Comment: I can post this as an answer, but I urge you to wait a while in the (unlikely) case that there is an unconditional proof.

Comment: OK, maybe someone finds an irrationality-proof, that would be very nice as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This constant is definitely transcendental, assuming Schanuel's conjecture. Indeed, let us consider two cases. If $u,e^u$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, we can consider the extension $\mathbb Q(u,e^u,e^u,e^{e^u})$ of $\mathbb Q$. Schanuel's conjecture says, then this extension has transcendence degree at least $2$. But if $u$ was algebraic, then so would be $e^{e^u}=\frac{1}{u}$, and then there would be only one transcendental element among $u,e^u,e^{e^u}$.

If $u,e^u$ are linearly dependent, we can instead use Lindemann-Weierstrass - if $u$ was algebraic, $e^u$ would be transcendental, so they couldn't be dependent.

Comment: Only one further question : Why does "$e^u$" occur twice in the set ?

Comment: Let $z_1=u,z_2=e^u$. Schanuel is a statement about the extension $\mathbb Q(z_1,z_2,e^{z_1},e^{z_2})$. Here of course $z_2=e^{z_1}$, but I kept it as that to highlight how it comes from Schanuel.